# eclim error while processing function, cannot ping server

Tags: eclipse, vim, eclim

I started playing with eclim a couple of days ago, but I hit a wall. When I start the eclim server I can't really use my GVim. I can see the server running and everything seems OK. I try to :PingEclim and I end up with the following problem.

[image]

The blurred part is DriveLetter:\Users\Username. I am not quite sure why this is happening. I set up the eclim server to run as admin, but I still get the issue. As you can tell I am pretty new to eclim. I would appreciate if somebody could give me a few ideas or a resource that I can read up.

I am currently running:

1. Windows 7 Home Premium
2. Eclipse Indigo Service Release 2(Build id: 20120216-1857)
3. GVim 7.3.46
4. Eclim 1.7.6

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try :EclimValidate to look for issues?